# DHIS2 - Data Visutalization/Reports

Tags: charts, configuration, report, dhis-2

I am getting `No Values found` while trying to configure report/charts in DHIS2.

I have been

1. Created DataElements
2. Created Category Options
3. Added a Category to include Category Options
4. Created a Category Combination item to and added the category created in Step3 in it.
5. Now updated the DataElements and assigned the Category Combination.
6. Now created a DataSet with these DataElements and assigned to the  2. organization units.
7. Using the DataEntry module the data is added successfully for desired time period and marked as `completed`.

But when trying to create a report/chart for these DataElments or DataSets, I am getting the message that `No Values found`. However when trying to create reports/charts on Demo site, everything works fine.

Is there anything that I am missing where while performing all the above mentioned steps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use the stored values of completed data sets, once must run `Analytics`.

See the image below for reference.

First Click on `Analytics and Data Mart`
Second click on the `Start export` with `Analytics tables update` check box marked.

[image]

**NOTE:** This action can only be performed by a user with `System Administrator` rights.